# Selecting records group by

Tags: sql, group-by

```
CREATE TABLE #A (Type Char(20),ID INT, ID2 int,Address VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #A (Type,ID, ID2,Address)
VALUES  ('Child',101,290,'CAT'),
       ('Child',102,290,'CAR'),
       ('Self',290,290,'CAT')
       ,('Spouse',103, 777,'DOE')
       ,('Self',777,777,'DOE')
       ,('Self',811,NULL,'yyy')
```

So, ID is unique in #A and ID2 is grouping so, records 1-3 are in one group 4-5 in one group and so on.
I want to display all "ID" where 
(i) for each group if the address is same for all records, I want to get the ID where type = 'self'
(ii) if each group, if the address is different for few records, I want to get the ID of self and the ID of other recods where address is different.
(iii) if there is no group i.e. ID2 is null, I want the ID of the records.

so, the output should be

```
102
290
777
811
```

eliminating ID 101 because 290 has same address and they belong to the same group.
keeping 290 because it is self.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this type of problem, I find it useful to translate the conditions into flags/measures on each row.  The window functions are very useful for this.

The following implements the three rules:

```
select type, id, id2, address
from (select a.*,
             rank() over (partition by id2 order by AddressCnt desc) as AddressRank
      from (select a.*,
                   (case when max(address) over (partition by id2) =
                              min(address) over (partition by id2)
                         then 1 else 0
                    end) as AddressSame,
                    count(*) over (partition by id2, Address) as AddressCnt
            from a
           ) a
     ) a
where (AddressSame = 1 and type = 'self') or
      (AddressRank > 1 or type = 'self') or
      id2 is null;
```

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eeeca/10).